# How to do sorting in template in Django?

Tags: jquery, django, sorting

I am listing all the file information in tabular form like this in Django:

```
<table border="0" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="product-table">
    <tr>
        <th width="5%" class="table-header-left"><a href="#"><span></span></a></th>
        <th width="25%" class="table-header-repeat line-left"><a href="#"><span>File Name</span></a></th>
        <th width="15%" class="table-header-repeat line-left"><a href="#"><span>Type</span></a></th>
        <th width="15%" class="table-header-repeat line-left"><a href="#"><span>Size</span></a></th>
        <th width="20%" class="table-header-repeat line-left"><a href="#"><span>Date Updated</span></a></th>
        <th width="20%" class="table-header-options line-left"><a href="#"><span>Source</span></a></th>
    </tr>
    <form name="form" action="/delete_files/" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {% load endless %}
        {% paginate limit files %}
        {{ endless_pagination.utils.get_elastic_page_numbers }}

        {% for choice in files %}
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="choice" id="choice{{ forloop.counter }}" value="{{ choice.id }}" /></td>
            <td><label for="choice{{ forloop.counter }}">{{ choice.file_name }}</label></td>
            <td>{{ choice.type }}</td>
            <td>{{ choice.size }}</td>
            <td>{{ choice.end_date }}</td>
            <td>{{ choice.source }}</td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
</table>
```

I want to apply sorting for th : `filename, date, size`. I have filename stored as a CharField, date as a DateTimeField and size as a integer in Django? I don't want to refresh the whole page for the sorting. What's the way to do this? Here's what I have thought:

```
1) Pass href to th into backend which do the order by clause and pass data into template.

2) Fill the data into template with sorted data.
```

Or can it be done using jQuery?

Comment: if you don't want to refresh the page, then yes, use jquery; use ajax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way is to use jquery.

That link can help you if you have table to sort:

http://tablesorter.com/docs/

Comment: Can you give me an example of tablesorter on my provided template above?

Comment: There is an example, you just need to add this js file to your site and than you will be able to sort by the name of your colums.